# AJAX call from function won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var usernameInfo= $('#usernameInfo');
var ele= $('#username');
var username= ele.val();
if(username.length >=6 || username.length <=32)
{
  usernameInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle" />&nbsp;Checking availability...');
  ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_check_username.php",
    data: "username=" + username,
    succes: function (server_response) {
      usernameInfo.ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
        if(server_response == '1')                                
        {
          jVal.errors= true;
          usernameInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('<img src="not_available.png" align="absmiddle" /> Not Available').show();
          ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        }
        else if(server_response == '0')
        {
          usernameInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('<img src="available.png" align="absmiddle" /> Available').show();
          ele.removeClass('wrong').addclass('normal');
        }
      });
    }
  });     
}
```

The thing is that i have used this AJAX call from another script that it works with working .php file (tested and working), but now it just won't... any help would be good. Thanks

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Anything in the JS console?

Comment: you wrote "succes" instead of "success", check if that's the problem

Comment: Chobeat: you are a genius :) U solve my problem... Thanks to both of you for the response

Answer (score 5):

```
          succes: function (server_response) {
```

You have misspelled success

Answer (score 1):

Its:

```
success: function(resp){ .... }
//you have spelling mistake there
```